# Exiftool and stay open - arg list not working

Tags: windows, exiftool

I am just using the exiftool in Windows with the stay open mode. All my commands I converted to write to the arg file did work but this one even not. Does anybody what might be the problem?

```
-overwrite_original_in_place
"-rawfilename<filename" "-FileName<CreateDate" -d %Y%m%d_%%f.%%e
D:\..\Eigene Bilder\..\..\DSC_3968.NEF
-execute903
```

I just checked the forum of exiftool and the community here but found nothing promising what I might do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay now after some trys and reading I get the solution:

```
-overwrite_original_in_place
-rawfilename<filename
-FileName<CreateDate
-d
%Y%m%d_%%f.%%e
D:\..\Eigene Bilder\..\..\DSC_3968.NEF
-execute903
```

Hope it will help some other people also to work with the great exiftool!